# viewWillAppear called after touch screen

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear

when B -> present -> C, it called viewWillAppear automatic, but after I dismiss from C to B and B -> present -> C again, viewWillAppear called after I touch my screen,
which is

1.B -> present -> C, first time ok

2.C -> dismiss -> B -> present -> C, viewWillAppear called after I touch screen

when I present C, viewdidload is called but the view didn't change after I touch screen and call viewWillAppear, so if I didn't touch screen, my screen looks like B, but actually, C finish viewdidload already.

c is a scroll view content with a table view, some answer mention about navigation controller, but I didn't use any navigation controller at all.

B -> C, called when I select from a table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let l3ViewController = Utl.getViewControllerWithStoryboard("Home", identifier: "L3ViewController") as? L3ViewController
        guard let vc = l3ViewController else {
            return
        }
        self.presentDetail(vc)  
    }
}
```

`self.presentDetail(vc)` is my UIViewController extension, but when I try to use `present(viewController, animated: false)`, the problem happens as well, so it seems ok about this extension

```
extension UIViewController {

func presentDetail(_ viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController) {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: false)
}
func dismissDetail() {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.3
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)

    dismiss(animated: false)
}
}
```

view C

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // some of functions
    dataKeyAndValue()
    calculateLabelXAndWidth()

    // some of my view set up here
    setProcessView()
    setScrollView() 
    setTableView()

    print("view did l3")

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    print("view will l3")
}
```

NSLOG like below

```
// B -> C first time
2018-03-19 11:50:45.885423+0800 ROLLCALL[5624:204120] viewDidLoad l3
2018-03-19 11:50:45.888306+0800 ROLLCALL[5624:204120] viewWillAppear l3
// back to B and presnt to C
2018-03-19 11:50:50.295844+0800 ROLLCALL[5624:204120] viewDidLoad l3
// touch screen
2018-03-19 11:50:52.369439+0800 ROLLCALL[5624:204120] viewWillAppear l3
```

I did notice this problem is start from use Lightweight Migration for core data, does anyone have same experience before?

Edit

I did use some of the alerts like below, for some situation.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "",message: nil,preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
    self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

**answer**

I change this method for the present from B to C, and it works well, does anyone can explain to me?

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
           self.presentDetail(vc)
 })
```

Comment: Please show relevant code

Comment: Did you add any `async` operation during view controller transition? like thread or dispatchQueue

Comment: I add  `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` for an alert to present, many times

Answer (score 0):

Try using viewdidappear instead of viewwillappear

Comment: viewdidappear was also called after I touch screen

Comment: You need to also use viewdiddisappear in previous page.

Comment: nothing change after I add viewdiddisappear in previous page